# create fixed size List of non-repeating permutations from list of elements

Tags: java, permutation

I have a list of objects `M := [A, B, C, ... Z]` and I want to create a new list N containing non-repeating fixed size "`f`" permutations of these objects.

So N would be `(for f = 2) [[A, B], [A, C], ...]` but should not contain repetitions like `[A, A]` and if `[A, B]` is set `[B, A]` should be ignored.

I have found things like `Guavas` "`PowerSet`" but this wont help me as it can not be "cropped" to a fixed size.

I hope i have stated my problem correctly.

f should always be 2

Based on http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/print-all-combinations-of-subset-of-size-k-from-given-array/ i've done the following:

```
private Set<List<Object>> combineObjects(List<Object> M) {
    boolean[] used = new boolean[M.size()];
    return generateObjectCombinations(M, 0, 0, used);
}

private Set<List<Object>> generateObjectCombinations(
    List<Object> M,
    int start,
    int curLen,
    boolean[] used
) {
    Set<List<Object>> returnSet = new HashSet<>();
    if (curLen == 2) {
        List<Object> data = newArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++) {
            if (used[i]) {
                data.add(M.get(i));
            }
        }
        returnSet.add(data);
        return returnSet;
    }
    if (start == M.size()) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
    used[start] = true;
    returnSet.addAll(generateObjectCombinations(M, start + 1, curLen + 1, used));
    used[start] = false;
    returnSet.addAll(generateObjectCombinations(M, start + 1, curLen, used));
    return returnSet;
}
```

It is working but I wonder if there is a "cleaner" solution. I want to eliminate the bool-array.

And no, it's not my homework. Maybe i am just to tired and should take vacation.

**EDIT**
Based on @azro's answer i restructured the code like this:

```
List<List<Object>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> M = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++) {
    Object outerM = M.get(i);

    for (int j = i; j < M.size(); j++) {
        Object innerM = M.get(j);
        if (innerM.equals(outerM)) {
            continue;
        }
        combinations.add(Lists.newArrayList(outerM, innerM));
    }
}
```

or even better

```
List<List<Object>> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> M = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < M.size(); i++) {
    Object outerM = M.get(i);

    for (int j = (i + 1); j < M.size(); j++) {
        Object innerM = M.get(j);
        combinations.add(Lists.newArrayList(outerM, innerM));
    }
}
```

I should really take a loooong vacation. Thanks @azro!!

Comment: Not really - what is your question?

Comment: Show some things that you have done yet

Comment: I know what you mean. It's pretty easy.. all you need is the Array with the Letters and a Foreach-Loop in a Foreach-Loop.

Comment: I'm sorry but Stackoverflow is not about making your homework. Please show that you actually tried something before posting your problem...

Comment: Look below, mine works for f=2 of course but also for f=3,4,...

Comment: @Mickaël B Sorry that i posted the question too early. I've added my current solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't wrote "f should always be 2" as the beginning I wrote a solution which works for `f>=1`, so here is the method and how to use it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> letter = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        res.addAll(letter);
        int size = 2;

        for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++) {
            res = addLetter(res, letter);   //add a letter to all
        }

        res.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
}

public static List<String> addLetter(List<String> already, List<String> letters) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String al : already) {
        for (String let : letters) {
            if (!al.contains(let)) {
                res.add(al + let);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

If "f should always be 2" you need only :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String al : letters) {
        for (String let : letters) {
            if (!al.contains(let)) {
                res.add(al + let);
            }
        }
    }
    res.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @azro that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best solution but here you are:

```
static HashSet<HashSet<String>> getCombinations(HashSet<HashSet<String>> s, int f)
{
    if(f == 1)
        return s;
    HashSet<HashSet<String>> newSet = new HashSet<HashSet<String>>();
    for (HashSet<String> ss : s)
    {
        for(String elm : A)
        {
            if(ss.contains(elm))
                continue;
            HashSet<String> sss = (HashSet<String>)ss.clone();
            sss.add(elm);
            newSet.add(sss);
        }
    }
    return getCombinations(newSet, f-1);
}
```

Usage:

```
String[] A = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int f = 3;
    HashSet<HashSet<String>> set = new HashSet<>();
    for(String s : A)
    {
        HashSet<String> ss = new HashSet<>();
        ss.add(s);
        set.add(ss);
    }
    System.out.println(getCombinations(set, f));
}
```